# How can an axiom be “false” under different interpretations of the primitive notions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

> [image]

I can’t wrap my head around what he means by the any meaning assigned to the primitives making the axioms true make o true… I don’t understand how an axiom could be true or false, it seems like axioms are always true and a false axiom is just not a axiom.

Comment: See Non-euclidean geometries wrt to parallelism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be confusing if we think we are talking about the real world of sets, rather that just a "model" that acts sort of like the real world of sets.

Instead, let's consider the theory of groups.  A **group** is a system $(A,*,e)$, where $A$ is a set and $*$ is a binary operation and $e$ is an element of $A$, that satisfies the following axioms
$$
\forall x,y,z \in A\quad (x*y)*z = x*(y*z)  , 
\\
\exists e \in A \quad\forall x \in A\quad e*x = x ,
\\
\forall x \in A \quad\exists y \in A \quad y*x = e .
$$
The first one up there is the "associative axiom".

Now, suppose we consider the following assignment for the prmitives:  $A$ is the set $\mathbb Z$ of integers, and $*$ is the operation of subtraction $x*y := x - y$, and $e := 0$.  Compute $(1-2)-3 \ne 1-(2-3)$.  So, under that assignment, **the associative axiom is false**.  [We conclude that $(\mathbb Z, -, 0)$ is not a group.]

Comment: Doesn’t this just mean the same as the axiom not applying to that system?

Comment: @NOCURE: Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Axiom of Extentionality

∀x∀y[∀z(z∈x ↔ z∈y) → x = y ]

The intended interpretation is two sets are equal iff they have the same elements.

But, notice that we don't define what the ∈ relation means, and so the Axiom could in principle be saying something other than our intended interpretation.

A true statement is any statement derivable from the axioms. But, we leave ∈ undefined.

Theorem: x = y → ∀z(z∈x ↔ z∈y) by Extentionality

This theorem is derivable from extentionality for any definition of ∈

And so, any statement of that form for a given definition of ∈ is true, under Extentionality, and that definition.

x∈y could mean x ≠ y, x < y, etc... anything.

And so, Extentionality could also prove the following theorem, given x∈y is defined to mean x < y

Theorem: x = y → ∀z(z < x ↔ z < y)

Under this interpretation of ∈, we have that two sets are equal if they are greater than the same sets.

Here's a strange interpretation: Let x∈y mean (y∈x)

Theorem: x = y → ∀z(x∈z ↔ y∈z)

So, if we force ∈ to be symmetric, then two sets are equal if they are elements of the same sets.

Analogy: Think of ∈ as a variable, and an interpretation of ∈ as subsituting a value into it.

When we prove theorems, we do so in an abstract way, we don't define ∈, and so whenever one proves some fact in Set Theory.... we are in reality proving a meta fact about any interpretation of ∈

So, If a statement contradicts one interpretation of ∈, then it is not provable for the generic, undefined notion of ∈

That is the point the book is trying to make.

So, we can conclude that a statement is not provable from an axiom- if there is an interpretation of the undefined primitives of the axiom, which lead to the axiom contradicting that statement.

This is important for independence results, proving that a statement can, or cannot be proven in a given axiom system.

Comment: This comment was extremely helpful

Comment: Last comment, when a axioms is “wrong” under a certain interpretation, the axiom doesn’t prove that interpretation?

Comment: Exactly it. I think that's a good way to think about it. It's usually introduced in terms of models. A interpretation is a model for an axiom, if assuming the axiom we can prove that under the interpretation the axiom is true.

Comment: More generally, this is extended to Classes, which are collections of objects. A class is a model of an axiom, if assuming the axiom is true one can prove that, if we restrict the universe to just objects inside the class, the axiom is still true. Or, the class "believes" that the axiom is true, Or the under the classes interpretation, the axiom is true.